# Can my computer act as a router?

Tags: router

I have Directv cinema plus which has to have internet connection, is there any way i can plug the ethernet cable from the cinema box directly into my pc and set it to act as the router?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up sharing of your connection on your COMPUTER (I assume your Internet comes some other way then Ethernet or you do have at least 2nd Ethernet cards)

   - [Internet Connection Sharing for Windows XP (and previous)](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/show/ics)
   - [Internet Connection Sharing for Windows Vista/7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/76617-internet-connection-sharing-enable.html)
   - [Internet Connection Sharing for OSX 10.5](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=mac/10.5/en/8156.html)
   - [Internet Connection Sharing for Ubuntu Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)
2. Set up static ip address on COMPUTER with INTERNET (192.168.5.1 or so)
3. Connect your COMPUTER with your Cinema
4. Set up static ip address on your Cinema settings with GATEWAY pointing to 192.168.5.1 - Ip address from range 192.168.5.X), as DNS servers you could use some google servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
5. Enjoy :-) As long as you've shared your connection on COMPUTER properly you should be fine.

Another alternative for you which seems more reasonable and future proof would be to buy router (there's a big choice of routers for ADSL, PPPOE etc) and plug telephone/ethernet cable into it. Then your router can be on 24/7 and you can share your inet for as many computers/cinemas as you wish. Then you could simply enable DHCP and WIFI on it. Then it's PLUG & PLAY :-)

Comment: the problem is that i have a router but i cant plug my modem into it because it doesnt have a usb port on the router for the modem to plug in to :(

Comment: Well you don't plug in the USB into it. You take out whatever comes into your USB MODEM (i presume telephone cable?) and put it into your router? If it's ADSL router it should fit right in it. Then you just need to configure the router. It's also possible you've got ETHERNET based router and telephone line internet then you would need to change routers for things to work.

Comment: the modem is a cricket broadband card usb modem (looks like a flash drive stick) so there's no other way to use ethernet or any other cables on it

Comment: Ah I see. Well you can always buy an 3G based router so that you insert your 3G USB stick into router and share it that way. 50% of cheap routers have this functionality ;)

Comment: well, this is nice, i cant tell if the sharing worked for 24 hours from now according to directv cinema lol, it says allow 24 hours for the channels to appear after connection

Comment: There surely has to be a way to test it :-)

Comment: If you want to share connection using wi-fi, you can use your wireless card (if you don't have one, you can use an wireless usb stick) to share it through a program called Connectify.

Answer (score 0):

You mean [Internet Connection Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing)?

[[Mac](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=mac/10.5/en/8156.html)] [[Linux](http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/archive/2008/11/13/how-to-do-internet-connection-sharing-on-linux/view)]

Comment: i think so, i cant plug my internet modem into the router i have because of lack of usb port, so i am wondering if i can just avoid the router all together

Answer (score 0):

The easiest/cheapest way to remedy your problem (based on the information you provided in the comments to @MadBoy) would be to BRIDGE your your network connections.  Assuming Windows 7, go to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`, highlight your USB network connection, and the Local Network Connection (which belongs to one of your Ethernet ports).  Once both are highlighted right click one of them and select `Bridge Connection`.  Creation of the bridge takes a few minutes, but once it is done you can plug an Ethernet cable directly from your PC to DirectTV.

Comment: I have Windows XP, when I highlight more than one connection and right click it shows status, create shortcut, etc, but no bridge connections...

Comment: In XP you have to go top `Control Panel\Network Connections` then highlight the network adapters in question, right click one of them, and select `Bridge Connections`.  Make sure both of them are highlighted when you right click or else you will not get the `Bridge Connections` option.